# Listening for Preference Changes using Mono for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to get an example from the book [Professional Android Programming with Mono for Android and .Net/C#](http://books.google.com/books?id=YDeNQia3BwQC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener&source=bl&ots=f8Hl0QJMVP&sig=mkk2oktnp_8nNhqVLEWqmXWxddw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sPirT9OiKObe0QHnr4n7Dw&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener&f=false)
(pages 202 to 204) working.

To register and unregister a change listener it shows the following code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Preferences;

namespace MonoForAndroidPreferences
{
    [Activity(Label = "User Preferences")]
    public class UserPreferences : PreferenceActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            this.AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Layout.userpreferences);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            this.GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Private).RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();

            this.GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Private).UnregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void OnSharedPreferenceChanged(ISharedPreferences prefs, string key)
        {
            // Do something with the changed value pointed to by key
        }
    }
}
```

Both `RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and `UnregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` of course cannot convert from `UserPreferences` to `ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

I'm not sure how the author meant for this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried downloading the sample code from [wrox.com](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-Programming-with-Mono-for-Android-and-NET-C-.productCd-1118026438,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) but it did not include the listening for preferences changes in the sample code.

EDIT:

The following code compiles, but `OnSharedPreferenceChanged` never gets called when an update is made in the preferences.

```
    public class UserPreferences : PreferenceActivity, ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            this.AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Layout.userpreferences);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            this.GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Private).RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();

            this.GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Private).UnregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        void ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.OnSharedPreferenceChanged(ISharedPreferences prefs, string key)
        {
            // Do something with the changed value pointed to by key
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
PreferenceScreen.SharedPreferences.RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

instead of

```
 this.GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Private).RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: SharedPreferences is not a static property of the PreferenceScreen class so I don't see how this code can work

Answer (score 4):

I was working through exactly the same example, and had no problem getting the OnPause and OnResume events to fire.

The problem was that registering/unregistering the listener on pause/resume worked, but had absolutely no effect. The listener itself never fired.

Switching to the actual UserPreferences intent caused the OnPause to fire, deregistering the listener. And vice versa, when I came back from it. But that was only part of the problem. I couldn't even get the  preferences to load properly using this method

```
this.GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Private).RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

(I assume the reason was because the activities I was using had different names, the launcher was called `PreferencesDemoActivity`and the preferences themselves were being handled by `UserPreferences` - see below).

Unfortunately the solution marked as answer above with

```
PreferenceScreen.SharedPreferences.RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

Doesn't work either (it complains about SharedPreferences not being available in a static context).

Once I moved all the OnPause/OnResume/Listener code to **inside** the UserPreferences class, it all worked perfectly.

However, that was no good to me. I needed my **MAIN** app to immediately respond to changes to the preferences, and not have to re-read them all when returning from the preferences screen, and check for changes.

The only way I could get the actual OnSharedPreferenceChanged listener in my 'main' class to fire when something changed in my (separate) preferences screen was to implement it thus:

```
[Activity(Label = "More user preferences", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class PreferencesDemoActivity : Activity, ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        // !!!NB !!! Remember to implement ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in this class, 
        // or you'll never get to OnSharedPreferenceChanged method
        PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this).RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        button.Click += delegate
                            {
                                Intent i = new Intent(this, new UserPreferences().Class);
                                this.StartActivityForResult(i, 0); // this ensures that we come back to this one when we exit the pref screen
                            };

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Remember to implement ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in this class, or you'll never get this method to compile
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sharedPreferences"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    public void OnSharedPreferenceChanged(ISharedPreferences sharedPreferences, string key)
    {
        Log.Debug("MUP", string.Format("Preference {0} changed", key));

        if (key == "PREF_AUTO_UPDATE")
        {
            bool autoRefresh = sharedPreferences.GetBoolean("PREF_AUTO_UPDATE", false);
            Log.Debug("MUP", string.Format("Preference {0} changed to {1}", key, autoRefresh));
        }

    }
```

That worked for me, and solved my problem. The key appeared to be to use **PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences**.

Comment: This seems to be the solution indeed. Would like to add that unregistering the handler in the onPause as suggested in the book also prevents the OnSharedPreferenceChangd to be called

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, you need to give those methods an instance of a class that implements [`ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Content.ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener). This could be a separate class, or if you want to use "this" as in that sample, modify the class to implement that interface:

```
[Activity(Label = "User Preferences")]
public class UserPreferences : PreferenceActivity, ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    // OnCreate, OnResume, etc

    public void OnSharedPreferenceChanged(ISharedPreferences sharedPreferences, string key)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Going with your recommendation I got it to compile by using "void ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.OnSharedPreferenceChanged(ISharedPreferences prefs, string key)". But it never gets called when an update is made.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that this is a symptom of the [issue I had with my Samsung Galaxy Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10757138/48700). When I debugged an app (that worked fine on an older Android 2.3.4 phone) to the Andriod 4.0.2 phone, none of the `OnStart`, `OnResume`, `OnPause`, nor `OnStop` events were getting triggered at all.

If you are working on a newer phone like this, try adding the "armeabi-v7a" as a supported architecture in your Mono for Android project properties.

Depending on your support needs, you may be able to [just offer the "armeabi-v7a" architecture](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Supported-architectures-armeabi-v7a-tp5069377p5070002.html).