# Mono for Android OnPause event not triggering on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, galaxy, android-event

I put together my first Mono for Android project (targeting API level 8, minimum Android 2.2) and deployed it to an HTC Incredible [1] running 2.3.4. Everything worked great and breakpoints in my main activities `OnCreate`, `OnStart`, `OnResume`, `OnPause`, and `OnStop` all triggered as described on Xamarin's [Activity Lifecycle tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Activity_Lifecycle).

Without changing any project settings, I swapped for a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.2 and deployed the same app. It called `OnCreate` just fine, but never triggered any of the other events when I switched away from the app.

How do I get these activity events to trigger in Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) on the Galaxy Nexus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While running the first deployment on a Galaxy Nexus, you will see it deploying the "armeabi-v7a - 40202" assemblies. For some reason that stuck in my head when this issue started making things difficult.

If you go to the project properties and check the box for "armeabi-v7a" under "Supported architectures", these events will start being triggered as expected.

[image: armeabi-v7a supported architecture checkbox]